Slidable issue with no primary and no ButtonStyle StyleFrom
I've added Slidable dependancy to my flutter project and then added Slidable widget to a Container but the debug console outputs this issue when building.
child: Slidable(
        startActionPane: ActionPane(
          motion: StretchMotion(),
          children: [
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: deleteFunction,
              icon: Icons.delete,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(....

The output
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_slidable-1.3.2/lib/src/actions.dart:102:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'primary'.
            primary: effectiveForegroundColor,
            ^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/outlined_button.dart:177:22: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ButtonStyle styleFrom({
                     ^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.

Here is my ThemeData that I use in the project:
ThemeData mainTheme = ThemeData(
  primaryColor: bcgColor,
  buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(),

  //colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Color(0Xfff7f2ef)),
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: bcgColor,
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: mainTextColor,
        fontSize: headFontSize,
      )),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    bodyMedium: TextStyle(
      color: mainTextColor,
      fontSize: bodyFontSize,
    ),
  ),
  checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
    fillColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      if (states.contains(WidgetState.hovered)) {
        return Colors.white;
      } else if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
        return Colors.white;
      }
      return null;
    }),
    checkColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (states) {
        if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
          return Colors.black;
        }
        return null;
      },
    ),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.5),
    ),
  ),
);

Please advise on what I could change.
I've tried adding some new Theme information but it didn't work

This was due to the fact that I've had old version of Slidable (1.2.0). I've changed it to 3.1.1 and everything works now.
